TypeError: Cannot convert numpy.ndarray to numpy.ndarray
I'm not sure why but after getting a new install of windows and a new pycharm install I am having issues with running some previously functional code. I am now getting the above error with the code below. Is it a setup issue or has something changed that now makes this code not function? Error happens on the last line. The error doesn't make sense to me as there should be no conversion required for ndarray to ndarray.
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as SQL
import torch
import datetime

# Setup your SQL connection
server = [hidden for security]
database = [hidden for security]
username = [hidden for security]
password = [hidden for security]
# This is using the pyodbc connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# This is using the SQLAlchemy connection
engine_str = SQL.URL.create(
    drivername="mssql+pyodbc",
    username=username,
    password=password,
    host=server,
    port=1433,
    database=database,
    query={
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        "TrustServerCertificate": "no",
        "Connection Timeout": "30",
        "Encrypt": "yes",
    },
)
engine = SQL.create_engine(engine_str)

storeemployee = []
regionalemployee = []
regionid = []
storeid = []

# get table from dev
with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(SQL.text("SELECT StoreId, R_Num, RegionalMerchandiserEmployeeId, StoreMerchandiserEmployeeId from Staging.StoreMerchandiserInput"))
    for row in result:
        # set your variables = to the results
        storeemployee.append(row.StoreMerchandiserEmployeeId)
        regionalemployee.append(row.RegionalMerchandiserEmployeeId)
        regionid.append(row.R_Num)
        storeid.append(row.StoreId)
storeemployee = np.array(storeemployee)
regionalemployee = np.array(regionalemployee)
regionid = np.array(regionid)
storeid = np.array(storeid)

# StoreMerchandiserEmail
data = {'StoreMerchandiserEmployeeId': storeemployee, 'RegionalMerchandiserEmployeeId': regionalemployee,
        "R_Num": regionid, "StoreId":storeid}
FinalData = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['StoreMerchandiserEmployeeId', 'RegionalMerchandiserEmployeeId', 'R_Num', 'StoreId'])

Edit -
Full Error Messaging:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Carter.Lowe\Documents\Python Files\Data Import 2.py", line 56, in <module>
    FinalData = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['StoreMerchandiserEmployeeId', 'RegionalMerchandiserEmployeeId', 'R_Num', 'StoreId'])
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Carter.Lowe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 778, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Carter.Lowe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 443, in dict_to_mgr
    arrays = Series(data, index=columns, dtype=object)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Carter.Lowe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 490, in __init__
    index = ensure_index(index)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Carter.Lowe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 7647, in ensure_index
    return Index(index_like, copy=copy, tupleize_cols=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Carter.Lowe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 565, in __new__
    arr = sanitize_array(data, None, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Carter.Lowe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 654, in sanitize_array
    subarr = maybe_convert_platform(data)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Carter.Lowe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 139, in maybe_convert_platform
    arr = lib.maybe_convert_objects(arr)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "lib.pyx", line 2538, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects
TypeError: Cannot convert numpy.ndarray to numpy.ndarray


full error message please.  It may help to see one or more of the arrays in data.  We can't recreate your data, so you will have to provide the debugging information (if you really want help :)  )

@hpaulj added error messaging to bottom of post.

What data types can your storeemployee, regionalemployee, regionid, storeid variables take before the conversion to NumPy arrays? Could you tack on some commands to check their dimensions, to see if there is a size mismatch? Have you tried compiling the DataFrame while keeping those variables as lists?

@TheEponymousProgrammer if I take the np.array() piece out I get the same error. those variables prior to being set to NumPy arrays are of the class list.

Additionally, they all have the same length (771).

Thanks for the additional information, it's very helpful! I've tried simulating your situation, but have been unable to reproduce it. I've posted a test script as an answer, and if you could run it to check whether it works for you, that would be very helpful with solving your issue!

If I had your SQL, I'd check the shape and dtype of the 4 arrays, and then try to make a dataframe with a subset of the 4, to determine which is giving problems.  I. E. the classic divide-n-conquer approach to debugging.

I just had the same error today and solved it by updating numpy to 2.0.0rc2.

This solved my problem. I also did a reinstall of Python too.

I had downgrade pandas 2.2.0 to 2.1.4

Had the same problem and solved downgrading pandas 2.2.2 to 2.0.0

As to today (2024-09-20), my solution was to pin numpy<2, i.e.:
pip install --upgrade 'numpy<2.0' 'pandas>=2.2'

Or the equivalent incantation in conda, poetry or uv.
This situation will likely change once newer versions of pandas or numpy are released. As of this writing, the versions are:

pandas==2.2.2
numpy==2.1.1


I've tried creating a simple simulation of your problem, but was unable replicate it. My suspicions are that it might be a problem with your data type, or an issue with your pandas installation.
Could you try and run the following example that I've created on your environment and see if it successfully generates the Pandas DataFrame? If it does, then your installation is fine, and you might want to iterate through and explore your data types in more detail.
# Version Information
# Python:   3.11.9
# Pandas:   2.2.2
# NumPy:    1.26.4

# Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string

# Create lists of different data types to test
num_items = 20

# Generate arrays
list1 = np.asarray([np.random.randint(0, 10) for n in range(num_items)])  # Integers
list2 = np.asarray([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in range(num_items)])  # Strings
list3 = np.asarray([np.random.random() for n in range(num_items)])  # Floats
print(
    f"Array 1: {list1} \n"
    f"Shape: {np.shape(list1)} \n"
    f"Array 2: {list2} \n"
    f"Shape: {np.shape(list2)} \n"
    f"Array 3: {list3} \n"
    f"Shape: {np.shape(list3)} \n"
)

# Save as dict and convert to Pandas DataFrame
data = {
    "ints": list1,
    "strs": list2,
    "flts": list3,
}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ints", "strs", "flts",])
print(dataframe)


turned out to be an issue with the numpy install

OK, thanks for letting me know, and glad it was resolved!

If you have two different version installed e.g one through pip and another through conda, this issue will be raised. Uninstalled both and then install recommended one.

Met the same problem with numpy==1.23.5, solved by upgrading to 1.26.4

My observation was initially rejected with the "unclear" mention.
I will try to be clearer in explaining my context:
I deliver an application through Docker to ensure cross-platform portability.
My development environment is Mac with an Intel processor.
The application code is identical regardless of the platform.
What can change from one platform to another is the hardware, the operating system, and the environment that runs the Docker containers.
Originally, the stack included in my Docker image was as follows:
a) Centos 8
b) Python 3.9
c) Pandas 2.2.2
d) Numpy 1.26.4
When running this image on my Intel Mac, there were no execution problems.
When porting this image to a first Linux system with podman 1.6.4 (instead of docker), still no execution problems.
However, when porting this image to a second Linux system with podman 4.0.2, I encounter this error "TypeError: Cannot convert numpy.ndarray to numpy.ndarray".
I then completely modernized the image stack:
a) switched to Red Hat 8
b) adopted Python 3.12
c) adopted Pandas 2.2.3
d) Numpy 1.26.4
The problem is still present on this last platform (absent on Mac)
Test case to check if the problems exists:
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dict(i=[0]))
print(dataframe)

The problem appears in the pandas._libs.lib.maybe_array_convert function.
This function is defined here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx
This is a C extension defined in pandas.
I have requested ChatGPT to rewrite the function in pure python and I have included this patch in my own code:
def patch_maybe_convert_objects(objects, *,
                          try_float=False,
                          safe=False,
                          convert_numeric=True,
                          convert_to_nullable_dtype=False,
                          convert_non_numeric=False,
                          dtype_if_all_nat=None):
    """
    Type inference function-- convert object array to proper dtype

    Parameters
    ----------
    objects : ndarray[object]
        Array of object elements to convert.
    try_float : bool, default False
        If an array-like object contains only float or NaN values is
        encountered, whether to convert and return an array of float dtype.
    safe : bool, default False
        Whether to upcast numeric type (e.g. int cast to float). If set to
        True, no upcasting will be performed.
    convert_numeric : bool, default True
        Whether to convert numeric entries.
    convert_to_nullable_dtype : bool, default False
        If an array-like object contains only integer or boolean values (and NaN),
        whether to convert and return an Boolean/IntegerArray.
    convert_non_numeric : bool, default False
        Whether to convert datetime, timedelta, period, interval types.
    dtype_if_all_nat : np.dtype, or None, default None
        Dtype to cast to if we have all-NaT.

    Returns
    -------
    np.ndarray or object
        Array of converted object values to more specific dtypes if applicable.
    """
    n = len(objects)
    mask = np.full(n, False)
    seen_types = {'null': False, 'nan': False, 'bool': False, 'float': False, 'int': False,
                  'complex': False, 'datetime': False, 'timedelta': False, 'object': False}

    for i, val in enumerate(objects):
        if val is None or (isinstance(val, float) and math.isnan(val)):
            seen_types['null'] = True
            mask[i] = True
        elif isinstance(val, bool):
            seen_types['bool'] = True
        elif isinstance(val, (int, np.integer)):
            seen_types['int'] = True
        elif isinstance(val, float):
            seen_types['float'] = True
        elif isinstance(val, complex):
            seen_types['complex'] = True
        elif isinstance(val, datetime):
            if convert_non_numeric:
                seen_types['datetime'] = True
            else:
                seen_types['object'] = True
                break
        elif isinstance(val, timedelta):
            if convert_non_numeric:
                seen_types['timedelta'] = True
            else:
                seen_types['object'] = True
                break
        else:
            seen_types['object'] = True
            break

    # Simplified logic to decide the result type
    if not seen_types['object']:
        if seen_types['complex']:
            return np.array(objects, dtype=np.complex128)
        elif seen_types['float']:
            return np.array(objects, dtype=np.float64)
        elif seen_types['int']:
            return np.array(objects, dtype=np.int64)
        elif seen_types['bool']:
            return np.array(objects, dtype=bool)

    # Default case, return original array
    return np.array(objects, dtype=object)

pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects = patch_maybe_convert_objects

Now the code is working without any exception
The problem is in the C extension of pandas in "maybe_convert_objects"

Additional information, the test case presented by "TheEponymousProgrammer" works perfectly in a container running on Mac and leads to an error in a container running on the platform with podman 4.0.2
